# How to add 2 Splashscreen in application

Tags: java, android

1. The first splashscreen hidden after 5 secondes.
2. I want to add a second splashscreen like the first before enter in MainActivity.
3. in @drawable/background_1 <= This is the first image splashscreen I added.
4. in @drawable/background_2 <= I need to add this image in second splashscreen.

> splash.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background_1" >

        </RelativeLayout>
```

> SplashScreen.java

```
    package org.sbynight.app;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;

    public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
           private static String TAG = SplashScreen.class.getName();
           private static long SLEEP_TIME = 5;    // Sleep for some time

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

              this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
              this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    // Removes notification bar

              setContentView(R.layout.splash);

              // Start timer and launch main activity
              IntentLauncher launcher = new IntentLauncher();
              launcher.start();
           }

           private class IntentLauncher extends Thread {
              @Override
              /**
               * Sleep for some time and than start new activity.
               */
              public void run() {
                 try {
                    // Sleeping
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*1000);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                 }

                 // Start main activity
                 Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                 SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
                 SplashScreen.this.finish();
              }
           }
        }
```

**Problem Solved - UPDATE OF POST -**
1.I create a "SplashScreen2.java" + "Splash2.xml" 
2.I added @drawable>background_2 (the second image of splashscreen)
3.I added to In Manifest splash2.....

> 4. In my SplashScreen.java, I deleted this code:

```
     // Start main activity
     Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
     SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
     SplashScreen.this.finish();
```

> 5. In my SplashScreen.java, Replace by this code :

```
     /**** Create Thread that will sleep for 5 seconds ****/        
    Thread background = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                // Thread will sleep for 1 seconds
                sleep(1*1000);

                // After 1 seconds redirect to another intent
                Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),SplashScreen2.class);
                startActivity(i);

                //Remove activity
                finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };

    // start thread
    background.start();
```

6. In my Splashscreen2.java, I added the same code like SplashScreen.java,

   > Surely with this code now to start the MainActivity.class

   // Start main activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen2.this, MainActivity.class);
    SplashScreen2.this.startActivity(intent);
    SplashScreen2.this.finish();

> Problems Solved! I have now 2 SplashScreen!

Comment: Where is your code? There is no possible way anyone is going to be able to help you without some explanation of what you're doing.

Comment: I'd be annoyed after waiting 5 seconds, after about 8 I'd likely be hitting the back button and then remove the app.

Comment: Solved! See the update of the question! Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0):

This use-case goes against the Android design guidelines.

Please think about how your users would get a good user experience using your app and get access to your content fast.

## [Designing Help into Your App](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html#your-app)

> ### Don't show unsolicited help, except in very limited cases
>
> Naturally, you want everyone to quickly learn the ropes, discover the
> cool features, and get the most out of your app. So you might be
> tempted to present a one-time introductory slideshow, video, or splash
> screen to all new users when they first open the app. Or you might be
> drawn to the idea of displaying helpful text bubbles or dialogs when
> users interact with certain features for the first time.
>
> In almost all cases, we advise against approaches like these because:
>
> They're interruptions. People will be eager to start using your app,
> and anything you put in front of them will feel like an obstacle or
> possibly an annoyance, despite your good intentions. And because they
> didn't ask for it, they probably won't pay close attention to it.
> They're usually not necessary. If you have usability concerns about an
> aspect of your app, don't just throw help at the problem. Try to solve
> it in the UI. Apply Android design patterns, styles, and building
> blocks, and you'll go a long way in reducing the need to educate your
> users.

Source: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you would want to add a second "splash screen". If you really did want to do it, why not make the `MainActivity` your `SplashScreenActivity` and then move onto a new activity from there.